# Using UUIDs instead of ObjectIDs in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

We are migrating a database from MySQL to MongoDB for performance reasons and considering what to use for IDs of the MongoDB documents. We are debating between using ObjectIDs, which is the MongoDB default, or using UUIDs instead (which is what we have been using up until now in MySQL). So far, the arguments we have to support any of these options are the following:

**ObjectIDs:** 
ObjectIDs are the MongoDB default and I assume (although I'm not sure) that this is for a reason, meaning that I expect that MongoDB can handle them more efficiently than UUIDs or has another reason for preferring them. I also found [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607171/267121) that mentions that usage of ObjectIDs makes indexing more efficient, it would be nice however to have some metrics on how much this "more efficient" is.

**UUIDs:**
Our basic argument in favour of using UUIDs (and it is a quite important one) is that they are supported, one way or another, by virtually any database. This means that if some way down the road we decide to switch from MongoDB to something else for whatever reason and we already have an API that retrieves documents from the DB based on their IDs nothing changes for the clients of this API since the IDs can continue to be exactly the same. If we were to use ObjectIDs I'm not really sure how we would go about migrating them to another DB.

Does anyone have any insights on whether one of these options may be better than the other and why? Have you ever used UUIDs in MongoDB instead of ObjectIDs and if yes what were the advantages / problems you came across?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Using UUIDs in Mongo is certainly possible and reasonably well supported. For example, the Mongo docs list UUIDs as one of the common options for [the `_id` field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field).

#### Considerations

- **Performance** – As other answers mention, [benchmarks](https://github.com/Restuta/mongo.Guid-vs-ObjectId-performance) show UUIDs cause a performance drop for inserts. In the worst case measured (going from 10M to 20M docs in a collection) they've about ~2-3x slower – the difference between inserting 2,000 (UUID) and 7,500 (ObjectID) docs per second. This is a large difference but its significance depends entirely on you use case. Will you be batch inserting millions of docs at a time? For most apps I've build the common case is inserting individual documents. The same benchmarks show that, for that usage pattern, the difference is *much* smaller (6,250 -vs- 7,500; ~20%). Not insignificant.. but not earth shattering either.
- **Portability** – Many other DB platforms have good UUID support so portability would be improved. Alternatively, since UUIDs are larger (more bits) it is possible to [repack an ObjectID into the "shape" of a UUID](https://gist.github.com/enaeseth/5768348). This approach isn't as nice as direct portability but it does give you a way to "map" between existing ObjectIDs and UUIDs.
- **Decentralisation** – One of the big selling points of UUIDs is that they're universally unique. This makes it practical to generate them anywhere, in a decentralised fashion (in contrast to, for example an auto-incrementing value, that requires a centralised source of truth to determine the "next" value). Of course, Mongo Object IDs profess this benefit too. The difference is, UUIDs are based on a 15+ year old standard and supported on (nearly?) all platforms, languages, etc. This makes them very useful if you ever need to create entities (or specifically, sets of *related* entities) in disjointed systems, without interacting with the database. You can create a dataset with IDs and foreign keys in place, then write the whole graph into the database at some point in the future without conflict. Although this is also possible with Mongo ObjectIDs, finding code to generate them/work with the format will often be harder.

#### Corrections

Contrary to some of the other answers:

- **UUIDs do have native Mongo support** – You can use the [`UUID()` function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/UUID) in the Mongo Shell exactly the same way you'd use `ObjectID()`; to [convert a UUID string into equivalent BSON object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/UUID/#convert-character-string-to-uuid).
- **UUIDs are not especially large** – When encoded using binary subtype `0x04` they're 128 bits, compared to 96 bits for ObjectIDs. (If encoded as strings they *will* be pretty wasteful, taking around 288 bits.)
- **UUIDs can include a timestamp** – Specifically, UUIDv1 encodes a timestamp with 60 bits of precision, compared to 32 bits in ObjectIDs. In decimal, this is over 6 orders of magnitude more precision – so *nanoseconds* instead of seconds.  It can actually be a decent way of storing create timestamps with more accuracy than Mongo/JS Date objects support, however...

  - The build in `UUID()` function only generates v4 (random) UUIDs so, to leverage this this, you'd to lean on on your app or Mongo driver for ID creation.
  - Unlike ObjectIDs, because of [the way UUIDs are chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format), the timestamp doesn't give you a natural order. This can be good or bad depending on your use case. (New standards may change this; see 2021 update below.)
  - Including timestamps in your IDs is sometimes a Bad Idea. You end up leaking the created time of documents anywhere an ID is exposed. (Of course ObjectIDs also encode a timestamp so this is partly true for them too.)
  - If you do this with (spec compliant) v1 UUIDs, you're also encoding part of the servers MAC address, which can *potentially* be used to identify the machine. Probably not an issue for most systems but also not ideal. (New standards may change this; see 2021 update below.)

#### Conclusion

If you think about your Mongo DB in isolation, ObjectIDs are the obvious choice. They work well out of the box and are a perfectly capable default. Using UUIDs instead *does* add some friction, both when working with the values (needing to convert to binary types, etc.) and in terms of performance. Whether this slight inconvenience is worth having a standardised ID format really depends on the importance you place on portability and your architectural choices.

Will you be syncing data between different database platforms? Will you migrate your data to a different platform in the future? Do you need to generate IDs *outside* the database, in other systems or in the browser? If not now at some point in the future? UUIDs might be worth the hassle.

#### Aug 2021 Update

The IEFT recently published a draft update to the UUID spec that would introduce some new versions of the format.

Specifically, [UUIDv6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format#section-4.3) and [UUIDv7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format#section-4.4) are based on UUIDv1 but flip the timestamp chunks so the bits are arranged from most significant to least significant. This gives the resultant values a natural order that (more or less) reflects the order in which they were created. The new versions also exclude data derived from the servers MAC address, addressing a long-standing criticism of v1 UUIDs.

It'll take time for these changes to flow though to implementations but (IMHO) they significantly modernise and improve the format.

Comment: `uuid v4` is more secure, mongodb id is predictable and vulnerable to record enumeration.

Answer (score 54):

The `_id` field of MongoDB can have any value you want as long as you can guarantee that it is unique for the collection. When your data already has a natural key, there is no reason not to use this in place of the auto-generated ObjectIDs.

ObjectIDs are provided as a reasonable default solution to safe time generating an own unique key (and to discourage beginners from trying to copy SQL's `AUTO INCREMENT`  which is a bad idea in a distributed database).

By not using ObjectIDs you also miss out on another convenience feature: An ObjectID also includes an unix timestamp when it was generated, and many drivers provide a funtion to extract it and convert it to a date. This can sometimes make a separate `create-date` field redundant.

But when neither is a concern for you, you are free to use your UUIDs as `_id` field.

Comment: Thank you, the truth is that I don't really care about by IDs holding information on creation date (I already have that as a separate column). Do you have perhaps any insight on performance differences between the two?

Comment: Hi Christina, actually there is an interesting photo in the MongoDB Java Driver which shows you insertion time when compared between ObjectId and UUID values https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-403. Fascinated to hear about the approach you took in the end.

Comment: UUIDv1 also include a timestamp and with ~6 orders of magnitude more precision. UUIDv1 encodes 60 bits of time (nano-seconds) compared to ObjectIDs 32 bits (seconds).

Comment: So why not just add a timestamp. Using an ObjectId , which is near to a GUID, and more secure. Unpacking the timestamp from it, to get the time of insertion, is suboptimal I would have thought?

Comment: @PeterColclough Of course you can add a separate timestamp field. But as I wrote, if the creation of the object and the creation of the ObjectId are the same, then that timestamp field **"can *sometimes*"** be redundant. What's "suboptimal" depends on what your are optimizing for. If you are optimizing for storage space, then redundant data is suboptimal. So what are *you* optimizing for? If the answer is query speed, then the speed of which query operation exactly?

Answer (score 9):

Consider the amount of data you would store in each case.

A MongoDB [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) is 12 bytes in size, is packed for storage, and its parts are organized for performance (i.e. timestamp is stored first, which is a logical ordering criteria).

Conversely, a standard UUID is 36 bytes, contains dashes and is typically stored as a string. Further, even if you strip non-numeric characters and intend to store numerically, you must still content with its "indexy" portion (the part of a UUID v1 that is timestamp-based) is in the middle of the UUID, and doesn't lend itself well to sorting. There are [studies](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/) done which allow for performant UUID storage, and I even wrote a [Node.js library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ordered-uuid) to assist in its management.

If you intend to use a UUID, consider reorganizing it for optimal indexing and sorting; otherwise you'll likely hit a performance wall.

Comment: would probably add that it should be considered carefully since not in all cases you'd wan't something sortable/ predictable. for example when generating session id's you should take the uuid v4 version (random).

Comment: How about sharding, can you use a non-hashed UUID for sharding or would you have the same problem as for ObjectID where the new writes would all end up in one shard?

Comment: no reason to store UUID as a string... standard UUID is exactly 16 bytes and typically stored as a raw bytes even in mongo. Nobody uses v1 UUID, only v4 (random) and v5 (sha1).

Comment: As @Dmitry notes, UUIDs are 16 bytes (128 bits) and generally _not_ stored as a string. MongoDB has native support and stores them as Binary subtype `0x04`. You're right about the unfortunate timestamp chunking though, that's a real pain. I wish there was a official UUID version that acted more like a SQUUIDs.

Answer (score 2):

We must be careful to distinguish the cost of MongoDB inserting a thing vs. the cost to generate the thing in the first place *plus* that cost relative to the size of the payload.  Below is a little matrix that shows method of generating the `_id` crossed against the size of an optional extra bytes worth of payload.   Tests are using javascript only, conducted on MacBook Pro localhost for 100,000 inserts using `insertMany` of batches of 100 without transactions to try to remove network, chatty, and other factors.  Two runs with batch = 1 were also done just to highlight the dramatic difference.

```
Method                                                                                         
A  :  Simple int:          _id:0, _id:1, ...                                                   
B  :  ObjectId             _id:ObjectId("5e0e6a804888946fa61a1976"), ...                       
C  :  Simple string:       _id:"A0", _id:"A1", ...                                             

D  :  UUID length string   _id:"9575edcc-cb70-4d63-97ed-ee5d624de87b0", ...                    
      (but not actually                                                                        
      generated by UUID()                                                                      

E  :  Real generated UUID  _id: UUID("35992974-21ea-4f61-b715-2dfaed663b73"), ...              
      (stored UUID() object)                                                                   

F  :  Real generated UUID  _id: "6b16f733-ff24-4172-83f9-e4f96ace6775"                         
      (stored as string, e.g.                                                                  
      UUID().toString().substr(6,36)                                                           

Time in milliseconds to perform 100,000 inserts on fresh (empty) collection.

Extra                M E T H O D   (Batch = 100)                                                               
Payload   A     B     C     D     E     F       % drop A to F                                  
--------  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----    ------------                                   
None      2379  2386  2418  2492  3472  4267    80%                                            
512       2934  2928  3048  3128  4151  4870    66%                                            
1024      3249  3309  3375  3390  4847  5237    61%                                            
2048      3953  3832  3987  4342  5448  5888    49% 
4096      6299  6343  6199  6449  7634  8640    37%                                            
8192      9716  9292  9397 10816 11212 11321    16% 

Extra              M E T H O D   (Batch = 1)                                          
Payload   A      B      C      D      E      F       % drop A to F              
--------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----                              
None      48006  48419  49136  48757  50649  51280   6.8%                       
1024      50986  50894  49383  49373  51200  51821   1.2%
```

This was a quicky test but it seems clear that basic strings and ints as `_id` are roughly the same speed but actually *generating* a UUID adds time -- especially if you take the string version of the `UUID()` object, e.g. `UUID().toString().substr(6,36)`   It is also worth noting that constructing an `ObjectId` appears to be as quick.

Answer (score 2):

`UUID` are `128` bit (16 byte) and are globally unique. See [RFC 4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

`Object Ids` are a MongoDB specific construct and is `96` bits (12 bytes). And although it would be enough to provide uniqueness globally but there are some edge conditions. MongoDB has [this official document](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb) to compare the two.

We prefer to not be tied down with MongoDB specific ID generation and prefer to do it on the client side. We also use multiple kinds of databases. The bottom line is that choosing `UUID` over `ObjectId` is a decision one can take based on their specific use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I have been thinking about this for last several weeks. What I simply found is ObjectId and UUID both are unique. In fact in collection level you can not have duplicate _id whatever type you use. Some Of the answers talked about insertion performance. The important thing is it is not about insertion performance it needs to be indexing performance. That needs to be counted based on how much ram you are going to use for indexing _ids. We know that ObjectId is 12 bytes where UUID is 36 bytes. It says that for same amount of index you will need 2 times more ram space if you use UUID instead of ObjectId.

So from that point of view it is better to use ObjectId over UUID in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I found these [Benchmarks](https://github.com/Restuta/mongo.Guid-vs-ObjectId-performance) sometime ago when I had the same question. 
They basically show that using a Guid instead of ObjectId causes Index Performance drop.

I would anyways recommend that you customize the Benchmarks to imitate your specific real life scenario and see how the numbers look like, one cannot rely 100% on generic Benchmarks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
    const uuid = require('uuid')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const YourSchema = new Schema({
  _id:{
    type: String,
        default: () => uuid.v4().replace(/\-/g, ""), 
   }


})
```