# How to convert string to MongoDB objectId

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I have a content like `this is my content` and I want to store it to the MongoDB collection.
The problem is I want to update my data  and I want to find the `_id` of data on the collection without send the query to database.
I came up withe the idea to generate my `_id`s based on the content of my document.
I tried to convert the content to the sha256 or ... and then by using the `bson.ObjectId` in python generate my `_id` so any time I want to  update for example the `timestamp` in my collection I simply generate the `_id` and send an update query to the database collection.
But I facing an error below:

```
bson.errors.InvalidId: '3e2550e3ffd205d10900d893dd8d91be9f446d60' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string
```

I wondering if the idea is wrong or ...
Could you please guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is fine; the trick is you do not have to use the `ObjectId` type for the `_id` field.  The following pseudocode works fine where the `_id` is a `String`:

```
String sid = hex(sha256("this"+"is"+"my"+"content"));
Document doc = {_id:sid, theTimestamp:ISODate(), ... }
db.collection.insert(doc);
...
db.collection.update({_id:sid}, {$set: {theTimestamp:ISODate()});
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want to store ```_id``` as string.I tested your suggestion.But pymongo stores the ```_id``` as an string

Comment: I don't understand.   You want to be able to construct the `_id` based on pieces of the data itself.   You later want to be able to rapidly assemble those pieces and do a fast lookup (or update) directly to the `_id`.   That means `_id` needs to be `string`.  `ObjectId` is useful as a "nearly-unique" ID when you do NOT want to construct the `_id` yourself.

Comment: As you know use a string as ```_id``` causes queries slow down.So the ```_id``` have to be ```ObjectId``` or ```int``` or something like that to prevent the query slowness .

Comment: That is not true.   Where did you read that?   The basic performance is the same for any type in `_id`; the length of the key could make a slight difference.   `ObjectId` is represented as 12 bytes of data.  A `string` of length 12 bytes or so will have the same performance.   A string of 64 bytes might be slightly less.  `_id` automatically carries a unique index AND uses the special IDHACK in the lookup plan (shown in explain() ).

Comment: This may be useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895067/using-uuids-instead-of-objectids-in-mongodb